# Conditionally chaining promises not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I'm using React with Typescript and have this function:

```
const saveData = (): Promise<any> => {
        const promise = new Promise((s:any,f:any) => s(true))

        if (true) {
            promise.then(() => 5)
        }

        return promise
}
```

I then pass it as a handler prop to some component:

```
<Component save={() => {saveData().then(a => console.log)}}
```

This always logs `true` when it should log `5` instead, why? how do I effectively chain these promises. what I'm I doing wrong here?

This is a codesandbox.io example:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-montalcini-5njyg

Comment: Try a `return promise.then(...)`

Comment: did not work, still getting `true` in the console.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`then` does not change the promise it is invoked on, it returns a new promise which you ignore. Either store it back in `promise` or return it directly

```
const saveData = (): Promise<any> => {
        const promise = new Promise((s:any,f:any) => s(true))

        if (true as boolean) { // as boolean to make ts not complain about unreachable code
            return promise.then(() => 5)
        }

        return promise
}
```

Also consider using  async/await with promises, makes for a much nicer coding experience:

```
const saveData = async (): Promise<any> => {
        await Promise.resolve();

        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            return 5
        }
        return 0;
}
```